# Align Fragment to center in Activity

Tags: android

I have a Activity and i'm adding it on Button click, now when the fragment appears it is to the top-left of the screen.
I want it to appear in the center on button click.

Here's the code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.veeresh.photogallery.AddImage"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:id="@+id/addFragment">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Adding to Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            AddImage addImage = new AddImage();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLayout, addImage);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Please show code of R.id.mainLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use this below xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <FrameLayout 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/addFragment">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No need of adding Relative layout as the parent

Comment: without RelativeLayout use of android:layout_centerInParent="true" is invalid. so you should use this!

Comment: if this solution helped you, please accept the answer.